# Python 2.7's equivalent for bash -x

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there an equivalent of `bash -x` in Python 2.7?

In case you are new to bash,

```
$ ./hello.sh
Hello world
Hello world
Hello world
Hello world
Hello world
$ bash -x ./hello.sh
+ var=5
++ seq 1 5
+ for i in '`seq 1 $var`'
+ echo 'Hello world'
Hello world
+ for i in '`seq 1 $var`'
+ echo 'Hello world'
Hello world
+ for i in '`seq 1 $var`'
+ echo 'Hello world'
Hello world
+ for i in '`seq 1 $var`'
+ echo 'Hello world'
Hello world
+ for i in '`seq 1 $var`'
+ echo 'Hello world'
Hello world
```

This helps in debugging the flow etc quickly even for a very long running script.

Comment: [debugger](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html)?

Comment: As I mentioned, this is for long running scripts where the nth loop might fail because of a problem in the data. I find that this is different from debugging when you don't know where and why the script has failed/is hanging.

Comment: That would be called line tracing. It can be done with the [`trace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html) module's `-t` option: `python -m trace -t somefile.py`

Comment: Thanks Dan. Is there a way to get the calls for my code alone and prevent modules other than the ones I am interested in?